# How to set scoped param value in form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm refactoring my app's routes to address the [rule of thumb](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) because my routes are very lengthy.

Imagine that I have the following models

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :jobs
  ...
end
...
```

and my routes look like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :companies do
    resources :projects do
      resources :jobs
    end
  end
end
```

After the user's logged in, I set the `@current_user` and the companies that he has access to - `@current_user.companies`. With this approach, I avoid hitting the database when users tempered the URL to access unauthorized resources. For example, when a user edits a job:

```
/companies/1/projects/30/jobs/20/edit

class JobsController < ApplicationController 
  def edit
    @project = @company.projects.find(params[:project_id]) 
    @job = @project.jobs.find(params[:job_id])
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

I followed the example from [guides and added scope with a prefixed named parameter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers) to shorten one level of nested resources.

```
scope ':company_id' do
  resources :projects do
    resources :jobs
  end
end
```

So far so good, I had successfully shortened my URLs from

```
/companies/1/projects/30/jobs/20/edit
edit_company_project_job_path(@company, @project, @job)
```

to

```
/1/projects/30/jobs/20/edit
edit_project_job_path(@company, @project, @job)
```

But then I broke my `form_with model: [@company, @project, @job]` because it fails to infer prefixed named parameter - `:compay_id`, even when I specify it `@company.id`.

The only solution I come with was setting the named route back again

```
scope ':company_id' as: 'company' do
  resources :projects do
    resources :jobs
  end
end
```

Isn't It the same as before? I just shorted the URL `/1/projects/30/jobs/20/edit` but the path is back to the original `edit_company_project_job_path(@company, @project, @job)`. Am I missing something? I'd love to know how you do it

Comment: You do know that "rule of thumb" is an expression and not an actual rule? You might want to actually write out what it is that you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key is to use the `:as` attribute when specifying the scope. This will make it work as expected with `form_with` and other helpers that rely on `url_for`.

I just submitted a [documentation update Pull Request to Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46408) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You really misunderstood that rule completely. What Jamis Buck is refering to is that:

```
/users/1/articles/1
```

Can be shortened to:

```
/articles/1
```

What you have created is a vanity route that is actually equivalent to:

```
:username/articles/1
```

And sure `bob/articles` looks pretty but it has some serious problems. If you let users select user names and place them on the root "namespace" on your routes you will have to deal with the issue that usernames can clash with any existing or planned routes of your application. Is it really worth it for "pretty urls"?

`:username/articles` is also less RESTful than `users/:username/articles` as you have actually lost a level of contextual information that describes the resource. REST is about meaningful URLs. Not short and pretty URLs.

Comment: I made up the example but it wasn't clear enough, sorry @max. I already refactor it.

Comment: Once again, it's a fake example to explain my point, my goal isn't a pretty URL but instead reduce two levels of nesting following the Jamis Buck article.

Something like `/companies/1/branches/29/shopes/1/employes`,  `/companies/1/branches/29/shopes/1/employes/18/edit`, etc. Users only have access to some resources depending on their contracts and roles. Once again, another made-up example. I need a company and a branch to make sure they only have access to their shops.

Comment: What you're doing there is falling into this pretty common trap of mixing up the concepts of nested resources and authorization. Your RESTful API should ideally really only describe the resources and their relations to each other. Its not really the routes job to decide who gets access to what. Thats something you actually implement with Pundit or CanCanCan.

Comment: Also the `as:` option does not actually affect the routes themselves. It just effects the names of the helper methods.

Comment: I do that because I used the logged user to find the company `@company 
= current_user.companies.find(params[:company_id])`. Then know that he has access to the branch passed in the URL... Otherwise, I could have a security problem getting a record from the database when users tempered the URL.  
How do you recommend doing it?

Comment: Btw, I was starting applying pundit when I begin with my routes refactoring.